# What are the Jar files required to connect from Wso2DSS to CassandraDB

Tags: cassandra, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am connecting from Wso2DSS to CassandraDB, i added the (apache-cassandra-cql-1.0.3,cassandra-all-0.8.0-beta2) jar files, still I am getting the following error.

```
  java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: this exception has nothing to do with how you are connecting its to do with your configurations. Can you post the full stack trace and the message the exception is giving you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest versions of DSS (> v.3.0.0), the Cassandra JDBC driver which is used to connect to Cassandra via JDBC, is by default shipped with DSS. Therefore, it's just a matter of configuring your data source in DSS (as a carbon datasource or an inline datasource in the data service descriptor file) with the driverClassName "org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver" and other relevant parameters like JDBC URL, username, password, etc, and pointing to it within the data service descriptor. (.dbs file)

However, if you're using any other WSO2 product such as ESB or an older version of DSS, then you will have to download the cassandra JDBC driver and the other dependency jars (if any) to CARBON_HOME/repository/components/lib, restart the server and then configure your datasources pointing to Cassandra.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Prabath

Comment: HI Prabath,

Thank you, It's really  working with latest Data service server,But when i am connecting using same configuration(added the "cassandra-jdbc,apache-cassandra" jar files in CARBON_HOME/repository/components/lib in  ESB) from ESB 4.6.0 to CASSANDRA database,

i am getting the following error.

 ERROR - DataSourceRepository Error establishing data source connection: org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver
org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error establishing data source connection: org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.

How can i solve this.

Comment: Will you be able to put the complete stack trace including the "caused by" clause which I believe would help in identifying the root cause.

Comment: Also check whether the cassandra JDBC driver jar is accompanied by the following jars. (These may be already available in CARBON_HOME/repository/components/plugins but in case if they cannot be located there, you would have to add them too to CARBON_HOME/repository/components/lib as well) : cassandra-jdbc.*.jar, slf4j.log4j12_*.jar, slf4j.api_*.jar, org.wso2.carbon.logging_*.jar